# Swift resize view based on shown Items with autolayout

Tags: xcode, swift, autolayout, osx-yosemite

so im toying around with Autolayout with a Storyboard.
So i have a View, containing a Button and to its right a TextField. (Sadly i cant post Pictures here yet) ;)

now what im trying to do, is that by default, when my view gets shown the button is hidden, and the view kinda resizes it self to only contain the Text field.
And after the text field is clicked (selected) the button is shown and with this the view resizes itself to fit the button and the Textfield.

I think i might be able to do that in code, by simply updating the View width with the width of the contained and shown items.
But i feel like there has to be a easy way to do that with Autolayout.
So i tryed many things, but it just doesnt work, no matter what constrains i add.

How can i solve this ? Thanks in Advance.

EDIT
i forgot to mention, even if i remove the button from the superview i get bad results, i suppose the reason is that the constrains get messed up if i remove the Button.
So thats not an Option.

Comment: You have to post the image to have better idea of what's going on and then some suggestion can be given.

Comment: http://up.picr.de/22463181ie.png   as i said, i want switch the visibility of the Button, and i want the view to resize accordingly.

Comment: Constraints haven't been highlighted.

Comment: sorry for that, here you go.    http://up.picr.de/22463278cz.png

Comment: You have to implement that in code. Make an outlet of the constraint which is sticking the textfield to the button and then update it in the code according to your requirement.

Comment: I think you should use constant...i.e. make an outlet of your button width constraint and use `constant` like `btnwidthconstraint.constant = 0` when hidden and when show give the other constant....simple